# Сколько памяти занимает w_char? C++

Tags: c++, unicode, char, wchar-t

В c++ есть символьный тип char, 1 байт. А сколько байт отводится для w_char? И с какой кодировкой работает w_char? Я слышал, что он занимает 2 байта. Значит ли это что w_char - это Unicode, или может и в другие кодировки? Может ли w_char быть более 2 байт?

Comment: `sizeof(wchar_t)` :)

Comment: @Harry это понятно, прочтите вопрос чуть внимательнее) Если мы возьмем sizeof от того же int, то результат зависит от машины. Вопрос как раз в том, всегда ли w_char одного и того же размера и с какой кодировкой он работает. Я плохо мысль выразил в вопросе, скорее всего, вопрос спонтанно появился)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wchar_t - это компиляторно зависимый тип. И уже разработчики компилятора решают, каким его сделать. Обычно в visual studio он занимает 2 байта и хранит uft-16 (если точнее - UCS2 + суррогатные пары). Такой формат родной для Windows и поэтому, это очень удобно. В случае Linux, gcc использует 4 байтовый wchar_t. Да, это немного растратно, но зато можно хранить сразу utf-32 - то есть, прямо unicode codepoint. Такой подход существенно упрощает расчет длины строки и разные манипуляции в отличии от подхода windows, где нужно учитывать суррогатные пары.

Но кто использует суррогатные пары (это когда для кодирования символа используются два 2байтовых wchar_t)? В основном это эмодзи и разные странные символы. А в большинстве случаев 2 байт на символ хватает с головой.

> Значит ли это что w_char - это Unicode, или может и в другие кодировки?

юникод это не кодировка. Кодировки это utf-8, utf-16. А юникод это просто таблица, в которой каждому символу приписан номер. Но в случае кодировки utf-32 номера совпадают с кодами.

> Может ли w_char быть более 2 байт?

даже хуже. В старых адроидах (до 2.2 какой то версии) в NDK wchar_t был один байт. нормально.

Answer (score 3):

И размер и представление `wchar_t` *зависит от реализации*.

На практике на большинстве систем — это `4` байта и `UTF-32`. На win — 2 байта и `UTF-16` (по факту — `UCS-2`).